# Large Data Set Concatenate Values into Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic

I have a view with literally millions of rows, this times out when running it for everything but can do selects within it to pull back snapshots of data.

**VIEW A (over 5000000 rows - Times out when running for everything)**
[image]

I'm trying to concatenate the Criteria name and KeyDescription2 based on column 0 and idno as distinct criteria then export into a csv or spreadsheet.

**RESULT TRYING TO ACHIEVE**
[image]

I have created an .asp page where I select the distinct Column 0 and idnumber from the original table then loop through to get the criteria name. This works fine BUT it takes 2 minutes to do 1000 rows, meaning it will take half a year to run the full report !! So need a better and faster way to achieve this. Does anyone know how I would achieve the result directly in SQL-Server itself.

Comment: For future reference, images are a poor choice when it comes to asking for help with data. Instead use text tables, such as those created with this handy tool: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
select 
    Column0
  , idno
  , grouppid
  , Criterianame = stuff((
      select ', '+ i.CriteriaName +': ' + i.KeyDescription2
      from view_a as i
      where i.Column0 = a.Column0
        and i.grouppid = a.grouppid
        and i.idno = '' -- `i.idno is null` if your blank value is a null
      for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'')
  , criteriatype2
  , keydescription2
from view_a as a
where a.idno <> '' -- `a.idno is not null` if your blank value is a null
```

Notes:

- This will not reformat your date value as you have indicated in your desired results.
- Even though this will be faster than looping, it is still not going to be super quick
- You may want to investigate the view and see if using the base tables would possibly result in better performance.
- In SQL Server 2017 you would be able to use [**`string_agg()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).

Comment: Thanks, running it now, its done 20,000 lines in 8 minutes so will take 9 hours to run the query if it doesn't time out... an improvement on before but you're right its not quick.

Comment: @Emma I initially missed this additional clause: `i.Column0 = a.Column0` in the subquery. The next step would be reviewing the execution plan for this query and the code behind `view_a` to determine if there are missing indexes or indexes that could better support the query.